# Percetile complications

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to find the bottom 33%, middle 33% and upper 33% from my dataset.

**What I need:**
I need to get the percentile for individuals in excel. I have hundreds of people and next to them the managers name so I have been using the below formula to get the percentile based on manager.

**Current Formula:**

```
=IF(G2<AGGREGATE(18,6,G$2:G$1000/(AS$2:AS$1000=AS2),0.3333333),"Bottom",IF(G2<AGGREGATE(18,6,G$2:G$1000/(AS$2:AS$1000=AS2),0.66666666),"Middle","Top"))
```

**Problem:**

This formula should have the words top, middle and bottom against every manager at least once. But I have noticed some managers only having a top and middle. Clearly I am missing something?

**Update:**
I have also used the below formula against just the numbers and not receiving 'bottom' at all

```
=IF(A1<PERCENTILE.EXC(A:A,33.33333%),"Bottom 33%",IF(A1<PERCENTILE.EXC(A:A,66.666666%),"Middle","Upper"))
```

**SAMPLE NUMBERS:**

```
6.31025416
5.18260342
5.25185395
4.57484582
4.99563873
6.31717482
3.49576271 
4.21992744
5.02853494
4.77338476
4.9579394
4.00174679
4.04134247
4.66614821
4.264681
1.94515737
3.96117421 0 0
1.35109777 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0.97126669
0.99805933 0 0 0
```

Comment: Can you confirm there are values in `A` that are less than `=PERCENTILE.EXC(A:A,33.33333%)`? Seems like a silly question, but just to confirm..

Comment: Thanks Forty3 - I cant confirm there is value in A

Comment: Can  you share a sample of the data (just a simple table showing the column layout (e.g. `EmpName | SomeValue | MgrName | N-Tile`)? And, if you are looking to get the n-tile "by manager" the use of `A:A` for the `PERCENTILE.EXC` function will be too broad.

Comment: Try just using the formula `=AGGREGATE(18,6,G$2:G$1000/(AS$2:AS$1000=AS2),0.3333333)` in the column and do a manual check to see if the result is larger than any of the numbers.

Comment: formula works fine for me: https://imgur.com/a/neNyV

Comment: Try it against the number I have Just added to my question - That's for one manager and only getting upper and middle

Comment: what are all those 0's

Comment: Should they be on there own line?

Comment: Should they be excluded?  Because of course you are not getting 'Bottom'  There are more `0`s than a third.  And so the bottom third will be 0.

Comment: The zeros are included in my data set - I will look to remove and see what I get

Comment: Wait, I will modify the formula to exclude them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude the `0` use this:

```
=IF(G2<>0,IF(G2<AGGREGATE(18,6,G$2:G$1000/((AS$2:AS$1000=AS2)*(G$2:G$1000<>0)),0.3333333),"Bottom",IF(G2<AGGREGATE(18,6,G$2:G$1000/((AS$2:AS$1000=AS2)*(G$2:G$1000<>0)),0.66666666),"Middle","Top")),"")
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly by the looks of it - No idea how you worked out what I was aiming for. Thanks you